# Let $P(x)$ be any polynomial of degree at most $3$.$\int_{-1}^{1}P(x)dx = P(x_1)+P(x_2)$, where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are independent of the polynomial P.

Tags: polynomials, definite-integrals

Let $P(x)$ be any polynomial of degree at most $3$. It can be shown that there
are numbers $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $$\int_{-1}^{1}P(x)\,\operatorname{d}x = P(x_1)+P(x_2),$$ where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are independent of the polynomial $P$.

1. Show that $x_1=−x_2$.
2. Find $x_1$ and $x_2$.

---

I let $P(x) := ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$
According to the question,
$$\int_{-1}^{1}\left(ax^3+bx^2+cx+d\right)\,\operatorname{d}x=ax_1^3+bx_1^2+cx_1+d+ax_2^3+bx_2^2+cx_2+d$$
$$\frac{2b}{3}+2d=ax_1^3+bx_1^2+cx_1+d+ax_2^3+bx_2^2+cx_2+d$$
I am stuck here. I dont know how to solve further. Please help me.

Comment: Hint: your equation should work for *all* values of $a,b,c,d$.

Comment: Take P(x) = x.  Your first condition is proved.

Comment: In addition, may I suggest that you drop the "please help me" phrase at the end of your questions? Your questions have been, and should be in the future as well, strong enough to stand on their own without an additional plea for help.

Comment: You are free to say something like " thanks for your time" or "any help would be appreciated" :)

Comment: For $ P=1$, any $x_1,x_2$ will do. For  $P(x)=x$ we must have  $ x_1+x_2=0.$ For $P(x)=x^2$ we must have $x_1^2+x_2^2=2/3.$  For $P(x)=x^3$ we must have $ x_1^3+x^3_2=0,$ which is equivalent to $x_1+x_2=0$.  If the formula is valid for some set of polynomials, it is valid for any finite linear combination of some or all of them. So if is valid for $ P(x)=x^n$   whenever $0\leq n\leq 3$,  it  is valid for any cubic, quadratic, linear, or constant function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By expanding and simplifying the equation, we get

$$0a + \frac{2}{3}b + 0c + 2d = a(x_1^3 + x_2^3) + b(x_1^2 + x_2^2) + c(x_1 + x_2) + 2d$$

Since this equation holds true for all values of $a, b, c, d$, we sub $(a, b, c, d) = (0 , 0, 1, 0)$ to get

$$0 = x_1 + x_2$$
$$x_1 =- x_2$$

as required.

Now to find the values of $x_1, x_2$, sub $(a, b, c, d) = (0, 1, 0, 0)$ to get

$$\frac{2}{3} = x_1^2 + x_2^2 = 2x_1^2$$
$$x_1^2 = \frac{1}{3}$$
$$x_1 = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$

so that

$$(x_1, x_2) = \pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(1, -1)$$

Answer (score 2):

You already have two fine answers, under the assumption that such $x_1, x_2$ exist.  Your own argument can be completed to show that they do indeed exist.  You have already reached the equivalent statement:
$$a(x_1^3+x_2^3) + b(x_1^2+x_2^2-\frac23) + c(x_1 + x_2)=0$$
which must hold for all $a, b, c$.  Clearly $x_1+x_2=0$ will ensure it holds for any $a, c$, and then you need $x_1^2+x_2^2=\frac23$ if it has to hold for any $b$.

Solving these two conditions, we do get two real solutions - i.e $x_1 = -x_2 = \pm \frac1{\sqrt3}$, so in fact we have also shown the existence.

Answer (score 1):

(a) Choose $P(x)=x$. $\int_{-1}^1xdx=0=x_1+x_2$.

(b) Choose $P(x)=x^2$. $\int_{-1}^1x^2dx=\dfrac23=x_1^2+x_2^2=2x_1^2$.

$$x_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},x_2=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$